# MVVM Design Pattern for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm

I am exploring the **MVVM Design Pattern** for **AngularJS** but I'm not able to find any related document for that, Most of the document based on `KnockoutJS` and `Silverlight`.

MVVM

Pros:

1. The only advantage of MVVM that it helps in the loading the view faster in case of two-way binding.

Cons:

1. We can't make the service call . If we want make call we have to include third party library like jQuery or knockoutJS.

For MVC we have both the advantages here. Which means two way binding is also there not as faster in MVVM and 
we can make service calls also without having the third party library. We use controller for both above things in MVC.

The above my points is correct or not? please any one help me.

Comment: angularjs is mvvm out of box so just read any angularjs tutorial

Comment: Could you please read my post once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link for examples: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

You can use Spring RESTful Services (or any services for that matter) for your backend, but since Angularjs runs only in the browser, the MVC pattern is moved from the server to the frontend. I suggest that you make the effort and follow the AngularJS tutorial to gain a better understanding.

Comment: MVVM

Pros:

  1. The only advantage of MVVM that it helps in the loading the view faster in case of two-way binding.

Cons:

  1. We can't make the service call . If we want make call we have to include third party library like jQuery or knockoutJS.

For MVC we have both the advantages here. Which means two way binding is also there not as faster in MVVM and 
we can make service calls also without having the third party library. We use controller for both above things in MVC.


The above my points is correct or not? please any one help me.

Comment: Hi, I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: Please reply above answer

Comment: Hi bagya, I think the advantages with using architectural patterns is that the code is usually easier to write, read and maintain over periods of time. Speed usually not the only aspect that you have to consider when making a choice. As far as the specifics of using the Microsoft specific version of the MVC pattern(MVVM) versus the version used by AngularJS, I cannot advise. ( also  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel for more information on this)